# Android webview not logging in

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-webview

So, I've developed a website recently where the structure is like: Login->homepage->(Do some stuff/ Redirect to other pages)

I've tested it on my laptop chrome browser & mobile chrome browser where it seems to work just fine. The thing is when I try to do the same, in an android app thorugh "webview", the login does'nt work and it stays in the Login Page forever. I've looked up other answers too, where they seem to suggest to enable javascript n stuff, which i've done. Is there an error with the javascript/html code????

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One|Ubuntu|Exo:600|Righteous|Stardos+Stencil:700" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="initstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="details" >
        <fieldset class="box    ">
            <legend>
                <b>LOGIN DETAILS:</b>
            </legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    UserID
                </label>
                    <input id="userid" type="text" size="30" required>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    Password
                </label>
                    <input id="pwd" type="Password" size="30" required>
            </div>      
        </fieldset>

        <div class="submitbuttom">
            <input onclick="login()" type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="main-footer">
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
    </footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXx",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXx"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function login(){
    var userid=document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var userpwd=document.getElementById("pwd").value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userid, userpwd).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
    });
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    window.location='Homepage/index.html';
  }
});
```

**SOLVED**

So, after much searching I found out that i've missed the line

"myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);"

in my app. Including it, solved the issue and now I'm able to access the website :)

Comment: If you're using firebase, why don't you add firebase authentication directly to your app instead of using web view? It'll be much better and faster.

Comment: @Yashovardhan thanks for the suggestion. But I wanna try accessing the website through the app. Apparently I missed out on a crucial line "myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);"
This solved it.

Comment: Glad to know your problem is solved